# What is it that comes once in a year, twice in a month, three times in a week and four times in a day?

Tags: lateral-thinking

What is it that comes-

- Once in a year
- Twice in a month
- Three times in a week
- Four times in a day?

Comment: I wonder if this has to do with the date/time it was posted: 2018-01-28 within half an hour of 12:08 GMT.

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps the answer is:

> The letter **R**.

Because

> It appears once in *a yea**R***.
>  Twice in a month, *Feb**R**ua**R**y*.
>  Three times in a week, *Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thu**R**sday, F**R**iday, Satu**R**day*
>  Four times in a day:
>        *One a.m., Two a.m., Th**R**ee a.m., Fou**R** a.m., Five a.m., Six a.m.,
>
>        Seven a.m., Eight a.m., Nine a.m., Ten a.m., Eleven a.m., Twelve p.m. (Noon),
>
>        One p.m., Two p.m., Th**R**ee p.m., Fou**R** p.m., Five p.m., Six p.m.,
>
>        Seven p.m., Eight p.m., Nine p.m., Ten p.m., Eleven p.m., Twelve a.m. (Midnight)*.

Comment: It seems to me that if the rule for "a week" here were applied consistently, then the answer for "a year" would have to be 9. Your answer may very well be right, but if so then the question falls in XKCD 169 territory for me.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Oh I agree, but it seemed likely enough to be exactly that kind of thing that hazarding the answer seemed warranted :)

Comment: This puzzle feels like a  [rip off](https://www.bhavinionline.com/2016/07/whatsapp-riddle-comes-year-twice-month/)

Comment: @prog_SAHIL if so, that makes me wonder about his other questions, if they are lacking the same attribution

Comment: @HerbWolfe and prog_SAHIL - In fairness, this is a distinct riddle from [that one](https://www.bhavinionline.com/2016/07/whatsapp-riddle-comes-year-twice-month/), or from [this one](https://www.quora.com/What-comes-once-in-a-year-twice-in-a-week-and-never-in-a-day) or [this one](https://riddlesbrainteasers.com/minute-twice-moment/), even if they share the same theme—which has yet to be seen.  A variation on the idea with a different presentation and a unique answer is not plagiarism and no attribution would be needed here.

Comment: Doesn't work if you use the 24 hour clock, though.

Comment: Seems a little arbitrary - would this answer not be wrong 11 months out of 12?

Comment: @Scott It says "a month", not "any month" or "each month". The answer meets the criterion for, well, *a* month.

Comment: I guess, 'inconsistent'. The puzzle this is based on, the puzzle is consistent - the same explanation explains all the lines. This answer uses a different explanation for line 1, and line 2, and lines 3+4, (which share a solution with each other).

Comment: @Scott et. al. Yes, I've already noted that I agree this answer isn't consistent. That said, I've also already noted that I posted this because I think it is pretty likely that the intended answer is this kind of answer—as I'm at a loss to find a consistent answer similar to the answers to "the puzzle this is based on" (a supposition we're all making, but which has yet to be proven). If it turns out this actually *is* the intended answer, your arguments would really be with the puzzle, not me. Of course it may *not* be the answer; in which case the answer is still out there. Go find it :)

Comment: maybe you can finde better solutions here:http://www.un.org/en/sections/observances/united-nations-observances/index.html

Comment: You can even write "Seven-HundRed HouRs".